# TYPO3 Error handling not redirecting after autoload

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I am trying to get a login redirect in TYPO3 to execute. I first created the vendorname/my_extension `stevongo/beleg` using Packagist, the php package repository. Next a `composer.json` on my directory and an `ext_emconf.php`. I then ran an autoload using composer. And my extention was successfully registered on the autoload_psr4.php i.e.

[autoload_psr4.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHWvF.jpg)

....this a testament that both `composer.json` on my current directory and root directory were well configured same as the `ext_emconf.php`.

My Classes path is also correctly set as `typoconf/ext/beleg/Classes/user_pageNotFound.php`

```
typconf/ext/beleg/Classes
           /beleg/Composer.Json
           /beleg/ext_emconf.php
```

My Typoscript is

```
    # Default PAGE object:
    page = PAGE
    page.10 = USER
    page.10 {
      userFunc = stevongo\beleg\user_pageNotFound->pageNotFound
    }
```

Initially I had created a Error handling function but after it wasn't executing I changed it to

```php
<?php
namespace stevongo\beleg;  

class user_pageNotFound
{
    public function pageNotFound()
    {
        return 'page was not found!';
    }
```

...so as to run a test while maintaining the same class and function name. This simple function at this point is supposed to work but nothing is going.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere, a syntax error should show up. The closing curly brace for the class is missing.